# Stannis's army beyond the Wall

Tags: game-of-thrones

How did Stannis Baratheon get his huge mounted army north of the Wall? This logistical feat is not explained.  Assuming an army of 25,000, it would be hugely time-consuming to go through the Wall's gates.